# Value get from dropdownList change only onetime?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have jquery ajax function to get value as parameter to my controller and send HTML back to may cart table.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Quantity").change(function () {
        var ProID = $(this).attr("data");
        var Quatity = $(".Quantity").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", url: "/Cart/UpdateValue", data: { ProID: ProID, quantity: Quatity },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".cart_box").html(data);

            }
        }
            );
    });
});
```

So in my view

```
<tbody>
                @foreach (var line in Model.Cart.Lines)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>@line.Product.Name
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; padding: 0">@Html.DropDownList("Quantity", new SelectList(ViewBag.Items as System.Collections.IList, "Value", "Text", line.Quantity.ToString()), new { data=line.Product.ProductID ,@class="Quantity"})</td>
                        <td>@string.Format("{0:00,0 VNĐ}", line.Product.Price)</td>
                        <td>@string.Format("{0:00,0 VNĐ}", (line.Quantity * line.Product.Price))</td>
                        <td>Button</td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>`
```

If I change the value in my dropdownlist, it happens only one time and only in the first row. Can someone tell me what my mistake is?
EDIT: This is my controller for Cart Index View:

```
 public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
        }
        ViewBag.Items = items;
        return View(new CartIndexViewModel { Cart = GetCart(), ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    }
```

and this is controller when ajax make request success:

```
public PartialViewResult UpdateValue(int ProID, int quantity)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
        }
        ViewBag.Items = items;
        Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == ProID);
        if (product != null)
        {
            GetCart().UpdateItem(product, quantity);

        }
        CartIndexViewModel ptview = new CartIndexViewModel {Cart=GetCart(),ReturnUrl="/"};
        return PartialView(ptview);
    }
```

Comment: is the event handler called only once or the ajax request is sent only once

Comment: Try setting the option `cache: false` to the ajax options

Comment: @ Arun P Johny: The ajax request send only once when i change value of dropdownlist in the first time. So the second time it's not change. Try cache: false, not working. When i have more than one row, when i changed value of one dropdownlist, it changed all the same in another dropdownlist. Sr for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are replacing old list with new list inside success -

In that case, you can try using event delegation like this-

```
$(document.body).on('change','.Quantity',function () {
```

Comment: Yes, and when i change the value dropdownList on the second row, it also change the same value on the first row.